# Get number of rows and number of columns in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, go

I am trying to read a big excel file in golang.
I need to find the number of columns.

I am using the https://godoc.org/github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize
library but I could not find such a function.

In python there is the https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.ncols

Anything similar in Golang?

Comment: If it's xlsx you can parse the relevant parts of xml using very little memory

Answer (score 2):

Excel doesn't have a fixed number of columns. What you want is the largest number of columns found across all the rows.

This is exactly what `Sheet.ncols` does.
You can get the same result with `excelize` by calling `GetRows`, iterating over all rows, and finding the highest count of columns across all rows.

Comment: my problem is memory. I have a python script that I want to port to golang. I am not sure if python reads the whole excel in memory.
go: More than 1GB of memory
python: a few MBs
Also in python I load and process the file in 13s and in go just to read 45s.

Comment: I suggest you file a feature request with the devs of the go library to allow for iterative modes as opposed to loading the entire sheet.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they have a function in the library that does exactly what you want, it's just not public. See [here](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize/blob/ebafbdde73e3e0498e547a2bd862552d9e304701/rows.go#L72).

I'd file a PR to see if this can be exposed publicly. The reason that memory is an issue is that the only method for getting the total number of rows/columns at the moment in the library is that a map is constructed of every single cell (see [`GetRows`](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize/blob/ebafbdde73e3e0498e547a2bd862552d9e304701/rows.go#L21)).

Comment: nice catch. Unfortunately it reads everything in memory when you OpenFile . I will investigate a bit more